# Creating Nested Structs, what will be a better way?

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to create nested Structs something like

```
<cffunction name="setDataAllWithFilter" output="false" access="public">

    <cfargument name="stCollection" required="true" type="Struct" />

    <cfif NOT StructKeyExists( Session, this.LOCAL ) >
        <cfset Session[this.LOCAL] = StructNew() />
    </cfif>

    <cfif NOT StructKeyExists( Session[this.LOCAL], "Data" ) >
        <cfset Session[this.LOCAL]["Data"] = StructNew() />
    </cfif>

    <cfif NOT StructKeyExists( Session[this.LOCAL]["Data"], "Filtered" ) >
        <cfset Session[this.LOCAL]["Data"]["Filtered"]  = StructNew() />
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn SetAll( Arguments.stCollection, Session[this.LOCAL]["Data"]["Filtered"] ) />

</cffunction>
```

is it OK like this? or there is a better way to do so?

Thanks

Comment: not really sure what you're trying to do here.  Why do u need to create such struct in session?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is it a better way to create a nested structre if not available? It can be Session, Request or any other LOCAL structure. What I wanted to ask is is there a better way to create such nested Structures? Thanks

Comment: are you turning a struct with many keys into structs within struct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is fine. You can use cfparam to make your life easier though

```
<cffunction name="setDataAllWithFilter" output="false" access="public">

    <cfargument name="stCollection" required="true" type="Struct" />

    <cfparam name="session[this.local]" default="#structNew()#">
    <cfparam name="session[this.local].Data" default="#structNew()#">
    <cfparam name="session[this.local].Data.Filtered" default="#structNew()#">

    <cfreturn SetAll( Arguments.stCollection, Session[this.LOCAL]["Data"]["Filtered"] ) />

</cffunction>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look to use [StructAppend()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f0b.html) to set up your session structure:

```
<cfscript>
initStruct = {Data={Filtered={}}};
StructAppend(session[this.local],initStruct,false);
</cfscript>
```

Not I've not had time yet to test this here, so ymmv

Answer (score 1):

The SetVariable function will create nested structures in order to satisfy the requirement.

```
 <cfset SetVariable("test1.test2.test3",4)>
```

Will create a variable test1["test2"]["Test3"] which equals 4.

Also look into StructGet which will allow you to create empty structs based on a path (string).

Comment: you don't even need to use `setVariable()` for that.. just Dot it away and structs will be created.